# react development server keeps crashing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, localhost, npm-start

am trying to build an ecommerce website to practice more on react. I have bunch of frameworks i installed for my react project, but recently, running react in localhost keeps crashing with this error info-

```
node:internal/buffer:959
    super(bufferOrLength, byteOffset, length);
    ^
```

below is a description of the error

```
node:internal/buffer:959
    super(bufferOrLength, byteOffset, length);
    ^

RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed
    at new ArrayBuffer (<anonymous>)
    at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
    at new FastBuffer (node:internal/buffer:959:5)
    at createUnsafeBuffer (node:internal/buffer:1062:12)
    at Function.allocUnsafeSlow (node:buffer:385:10)
    at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
    at new FastBuffer (node:internal/buffer:959:5)
    at createUnsafeBuffer (node:internal/buffer:1062:12)
    at Function.allocUnsafeSlow (node:buffer:385:10)
    at read (C:\Users\HP-PC\Desktop\react\ecom\node_modules\webpack\lib\seri
alization\FileMiddleware.js:597:32)
    at C:\Users\HP-PC\Desktop\react\ecom\node_modules\webpack\lib\serializat
ion\FileMiddleware.js:657:7
    at C:\Users\HP-PC\Desktop\react\ecom\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-f
s.js:362:16
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed my node js(based on a proposed solution i saw online), but am still getting the error.

Comment: incase someone runs into this error in the future, just update your node version and manage it with nvm. that helped me

Answer (score 0):

try to npm update to update modules , if failed try to remove webpack and graceful-fs

Answer (score 0):

incase someone runs into this error in the future, just update your node and manage it with nvm. that helped me. Was running node 32bit instead of 62bits.

Comment: Answer with specific information. 
1. What was the previous version of node?
2. What is the new version which solved the issue after update?
thx